# Using a Robot to AutoClick?

Tags: java, awtrobot

I thought it would be easy to write a script to just simply Left Mouse click and then `delay` at random intervals each time 3-6, but when I run the code nothing seems to happen? at least no clicks? any insight that maybe i'm using `Robot` wrong? I have read the JavaDoc. Thanks!

EDIT 1: I fixed the inital question and have updated my now working code. My only other issue is ***how do i slow it down***!!!! It is clicking at such a fast rate??

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class Main 
{
    public static Robot robot = null;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        click(100000);

    }

    public static void click(int desiredAmount)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int low = 3;
        int high = 6;


        Random rand = new Random();
        while (counter < desiredAmount)
        {
            robot.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            robot.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            robot.delay(rand.nextInt(high-low) + low);
            ++counter;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make a delay using Thread.sleep inside your loop.

Comment: in the beginning of the while loop, use `Thread.sleep()` to slow down the clicks per second? hmmm.. I will try to test this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your loop condition correct? Shoudn't it be

```
while (counter < desiredAmount)
```

Comment: ah wow haha silly mistake. Now i am getting the real error that i need to look into `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid combination of button flags`

Comment: at which line is the exception thrown?

Comment: I have updated my question with my findings, and would like your insight on my other problem.